# Unable to listen for events returned from Ionic InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, ionic2, observable, inappbrowser, angular2-observables

```
  let browser = new InAppBrowser(uri, '_system', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
  function obTest(event:string) {
    console.log('firing obTest');
    browser.on(event).subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    }, () => {
      console.log('object');
      debugger;
    });
  }
  obTest("loadstart");
  obTest("loadstop");
  obTest("loaderror");
  obTest("exit");
```

browser.on(event) is returning an observable that I'm trying to listen for, none of the console.logs are firing. I must be consuming the observable incorrectly. In the ios emulator the uri i specified is opening so the events should be called. console.log calls outside of the observable are working as well.

Answer (score 0):

the ionic command needs to have the -c flag in order to print console logs to the terminal, I needed to use the command ionic emulate -ios -l -c . The syntax for listening for event is correct.